# Why does Android AppOps (privacy manager) send duplicate events when user change his/her privacy settings?

Tags: android, listener

When a user changes his/her privacy settings through AppOps (e.g. denying an application access to phone contacts), AppOpsManager sends to anyone who listens what the users have changed (i.e. the package name and the operation (e.g. Read contacts)).

So I wrote a listener to do so. However, we the user make only one change, I receive too many duplicate events (e.g. 10 events that the user decided to deny Angry Bird access to his/her location) and then the app crashes.

Here is my code to register listners for each pair of package & operation:

```
public void startWatchingOperations(AppOpsManager appOps, List<AppOpsManager.PackageOps> opsforapps) {
    SharedPreferences myAppListnerPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_OPS_PREFERENCES, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (AppOpsManager.PackageOps o:opsforapps) {
        List<OpEntry> opEntry = o.getOps();
        //if I already assigned a listener to this pari of package & operation, then skip 
        if (myAppListnerPreferences.getBoolean(o.getPackageName(), false)==false) {
            for (OpEntry entry:opEntry) {
                //for each pair of package & operation, assign a new listener 
                ChangePrivacySettingsListener opsListner = new ChangePrivacySettingsListener(getApplicationContext());      
                     appOps.startWatchingMode(entry.getOp(),o.getPackageName(),opsListner);
                 }
            myAppListnerPreferences.edit().putBoolean(o.getPackageName(), true).apply();
         }
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the listener

```
public class ChangePrivacySettingsListener implements AppOpsManager.Callback {
    public void opChanged(int op, String packageName) {
        AppOpsManager appOps=   (AppOpsManager)context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        PackageManager pkg = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
                            //this is an object to store the event: package name, 
                            // the operation that has been changed, & time stamp
            PrivacySetting privacySetting = new PrivacySetting();
            privacySetting.setPackageName(packageName);
            privacySetting.setOperation(OPERATIONS_STRINGS[op]);
            privacySetting.setDecisionTime(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()).getTimeInMillis());
            privacySetting.setUserId(userId);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Her is the part of AppOpsManager.java that allows me to listen to user's changes.

```
public class AppOpsManager {
    final HashMap<Callback, IAppOpsCallback> mModeWatchers
        = new HashMap<Callback, IAppOpsCallback>();

    public void startWatchingMode(int op, String packageName, final Callback callback) {
        synchronized (mModeWatchers) {
          IAppOpsCallback cb = mModeWatchers.get(callback);
          if (cb == null) {
              cb = new IAppOpsCallback.Stub() {
                  public void opChanged(int op, String packageName) {
                      callback.opChanged(op, packageName);
                  }
              };
              mModeWatchers.put(callback, cb);
          }
          try {
              mService.startWatchingMode(op, packageName, cb);
          } catch (RemoteException e) {
          }
   }
}
```

I double checked to ensure that I've never assigned more than one listener to each pair of package & operation.

I would appreciate hints about potential causes.

[Here is a link to AppOpsManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3.1_r1/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the deceleration of ChangePrivacySettingsListener opsListner to be out side of the for block:

```
public void startWatchingOperations(AppOpsManager appOps, List<AppOpsManager.PackageOps> opsforapps) {
ChangePrivacySettingsListener opsListner;
SharedPreferences myAppListnerPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_OPS_PREFERENCES, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
for (AppOpsManager.PackageOps o:opsforapps) {
    List<OpEntry> opEntry = o.getOps();
    //if I already assigned a listener to this pari of package & operation, then skip 
    if (myAppListnerPreferences.getBoolean(o.getPackageName(), false)==false) {
        for (OpEntry entry:opEntry) {
            //for each pair of package & operation, assign a new listener 
             opsListner = new ChangePrivacySettingsListener(getApplicationContext());      
                 appOps.startWatchingMode(entry.getOp(),o.getPackageName(),opsListner);
             }
        myAppListnerPreferences.edit().putBoolean(o.getPackageName(), true).apply();
     }
}
```

}

And please let me know what happened?

Comment: Thanks @BasemAljedai. It solves half of the problem. The app is no longer crashing. However, I still receive duplicates when user changes his settings. I originally thought the location of the declaration doesn't really matter, but I was mistaken, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is helpful to someone, up to at least Android Oreo, calling  `AppOpsManager.startWatchingMode(op, packageName, callback)` will cause `callback` to be invoked when the setting is changed (1) for the `op` with any package, **AND** (2) for any AppOps setting changes with `packageName`.  This can be seen from the `AppOpsService.java` source, particularly `AppOpsService.startWatchingMode()` which registers the callback, `AppOpsService.setMode()` which calls the callback when the AppOps setting is changed.

For example, if you register a callback with `startWatchingMode(appOps1, package1, callback)` and `startWatchingMode(appOps2, package1, callback)`, 
when there is a change in the setting for `appOps3` for `package1`, the callback will be called twice since you have registered for `package1` two times.  If there is a change in `appOps1` for `package1`, the callback will be invoked 3 times, because you have registered once for `appOps1`, and twice for `package1`.

The solution is to register either for the set of AppOps you are interested in (without duplications), with the `packageName` parameter set to `null`, or register for the set of packages you are interested in, with `op` parameter set to `AppOpsManager.OP_NONE`.

Also you need to ensure that all listeners are unregistered (e.g. in `onDestroy` of your activity) using `stopWatchingMode`. Otherwise, the callback entries will accumulate across Activity lifecycles (until the app is terminated) and you will start getting duplicates.  This also means that you should keep references to all the listeners created.